# How to log tomcat6 JNDI jbdc postgresql dataSource?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, logging, jndi

I have a tomcat 6 server, that uses JNDI for its data sources.

How would we log a jbdc3 connector using this set up?

I know I should use a spy driver, or log4jbdc, but am not sure how to set those up in spring. I already have log4j configured and logging for an application deployed in this tomcat container.

What is the procedure to set this up for jndi, and to log the driver?

If i could have it "wrap" the driver without changing classes, that'd be the best route (and just wrap it at runtime via code).

Comment: *"If i could have it "wrap" the driver without changing classes"* That is exactly what log4jdbc does, so just use that in your Tomcat setup.

Comment: How? Would this be in a config file for tomcat? Or would this be per application WAR config file? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Wherever you're currently defining your JDBC URL, since you simply modify that URL to wrap the JDBC driver with the log4jbdc driver (and add the log4jbdc jar file next to your existing jdbc jar file).

Comment: So all i need to do is include the log4lbdc.jar in my classpath, and then decorate my datasource url with the log4jdbc driver package?

Comment: I haven't used log4jdbc, but if you follow its instructions, yeah, something like that.

Comment: Hmm, having some issues with tomcat finding the class for DriverSpy, despite the jar being included in the lib directory in the war / and shows in the classpath (via a servlet I made to print that out). Any ideas?

Comment: If you're configuring the DataSource in the `server.xml` file, then it needs to be in the `tomcat/lib` folder, right next to the existing JDBC driver jar file.

Comment: I'm configuring it in the applicationContext.xml (spring enabled application). I want to avoid dropping it there, as to prevent it form being available to any OTHER application wars in this container.